# Way to automatically escape characters ('_','\' etc) using knitr

Tags: r, latex, sweave, knitr

I m using Rstudio under Win7. Is there a way that knitr automatically escape a character? Please see below for a simpler example:

```
\documentclass[a4]{article}
\title{Example}
\author{Stat-R}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

<<nothing,echo=FALSE>>=
my_name <- 'hari'
my_number <- 100

df1 <- data.frame(my_name,my_number)
df1
# names(df1)
@

\section{Testing only}

Now I will print the columnnames of my data frame df1
$\Sexpr{names(df1)}$

\end{document}
```

**I get the following output...**

[image]

**But I want the following**

[image]

I will have to change all '_' into '_' in my tex file. Is there a way to directly do it in sweave file. I will appreciate any suggestion on this regard...

Comment: I haven't used knitr in a while but do you need the $ $ around the \Sexp{}?  I don't think you do and that seems to be what is causing your problems.

Comment: Without the $ $ around, the program does not even compile..I may be missing something...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you want to put the name in an verbatim environment rather than a math environment:

```
\verb|\Sexpr{names(df1)}|
```