# \Sexpr{} special LaTeX characters ($, &, %, # etc.) in .Rnw-file

Tags: r, latex, knitr

It has something to do with the default inline hook, I realize that and I have tried getting at it (the hook) and also read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11062497/how-to-avoid-using-round-in-every-sexpr?rq=1) and Yihui's [page about hooks](http://yihui.name/knitr/hooks), but I haven't been able to solve my issue. I even tried [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9896993/1305688) from Sacha Epskamp, but it didn't do this trick in my case.

I'm using `\Sexpr` and doing something along the lines of `\Sexpr{load("meta.data.saved"); meta.data[1,7]}` to print a keyword in my report, the problem is that people writing these keywords (people I can't control) are using special LaTeX characters ($, &, %, # etc.) and when they are passed to my .tex file without an `\` I'm having a bad time.

I have an .Rnw file with this code,

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
 Look \Sexpr{foo <- "me&you"; foo} at this.
\end{document}
```

Thsi creates an .tex file with an illegal LaTeX character. Like this,

```
<!-- Preamble omitted for this example. -->
\begin{document}
 Look me&you at this.
\end{document}
```

I'm interested to get an output that looks like this,

```
<!-- Preamble omitted for this example. -->
\begin{document}
 Look me\&you at this.
\end{document}
```

Sorry for the simple question, but can someone help me, and maybe others, getting starting on how to modify the default inline hook for `\Sexpr`?

Comment: why do you fail to give us a reproducible example? I really can't see why do you want hook \Sexpr?

Comment: @agstudy, tahnk you for your comment and sorry for not providing a reproducible example. If I have an R object that is `(foo <- "me&you")` and pass that you `\Sexpr{foo}` the .tex-file ends up with a & without an `\` and it should have been `\&`. I'll try to make a reproducible example.

Comment: And edit your question please , better than putting it in the comment.

Comment: I'm surprised that Sacha's verbatim idea didn't work. That seems like the right thing to do here, rather than adding backslashes before all the special characters.

Comment: @Aaron yes it is amazing but \verb command doesn't work in this case.

Comment: @agstudy @Aaron I'm also very surprised `\verb|\Sexpr{'me&you'}|` did not work for you, but it works for me with TeXLive 2012 under Ubuntu and also with MikTeX 2.9 under Windows. Perhaps it is a LaTeX problem? Update your LaTeX packages first?

Comment: @Yihui,@Aaron +agstudy  Thank you for all your help and feedback. It's most likely my LaTeX installation. I'm on a TeX Live 2009/Debian.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution provided by @agstudy has shown the basic idea, and here is a more robust version:

```
hook_inline = knit_hooks$get('inline')
knit_hooks$set(inline = function(x) {
  if (is.character(x)) x = knitr:::escape_latex(x)
  hook_inline(x)
})
```

It only modifies the default inline hook when the inline result is character (otherwise just use the default hook). I have an internal function `escape_latex()` which hopefully escapes all special LaTeX characters correctly.

Comment: This worked when I knit with the RStudio button. When I use a driver rscript to iterate over different data sets, all my figures don't display. Instead I see the their latex label name. I'm using to knit2pdf in the driver script. How would we have the same functionality but running knit2pdf?

Comment: This allows me to use pipes inline which is awesome. But I get a message saying Error: unexpected input in "\" for every expression with these escaped characters. Is there a way to handle that?

Answer (score 3):

Hooking works in this case. I customize it like this :

```
inline_hook <- function(x) {
  x <- gsub("\\&", "\\\\&", x)
  x <- gsub("\\$", "\\\\$", x)
  ## good luck for all Latex special character  
  ## $ % _  {  }  &  ~   ^  <  >   |  \ 
}
knit_hooks$set(inline = inline_hook)
```

Then

```
 knit(input='report.Rnw')
```

Will reproduce your report.tex.

PS: I think it is better to not to allow users do what they want.