# highlight all inline \Sexpr{} outputs in the generated pdf

Tags: r, latex, knitr, sweave

I am using knitr for a report wherein I have a lot of inline output text, mostly numeric values, using `\Sexpr{}`. I want to highlight **All** these inline outputs in my generated pdf.

Example code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}

<<echo=FALSE, include=FALSE>>=
N <- 100 # Total
N_f <- 60 # Women
@

There were \Sexpr{N} people in the company, \Sexpr{N_f} women and \Sexpr{N - N_f} men.

\end{document}
```

Hence, in the output all the number should be highlighted, i.e. with a shaded background (similar to using with `\hl{}` with the `\usepackage{soul}`).

It seems to me that the solution would use one of the [inline output hooks](http://yihui.name/knitr/hooks/#output_hooks). Another possibility might be to write a LaTeX function which search all the \Sexpr{...} expressions in the entire document and highlights them in the generated pdf. I am still learning and can not figure out how to implement these.

Thanks for any help or hints.

Note: The [knitr page](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/output/) by yihui talks about manipulation of the numeric value (scientific notation, digits after decimal points) which I have got covered.

Comment: Output hooks are exactly the right approach. What have you tried so far to use them? Using LaTeX to manipulate `\Sexpr{}` cannot work because by the time TEX "sees" your document `knitr` already processed all the `\Sexpr` commands, replacing them by their output.

Comment: @ CL. I had used the output hooks for manipulating the numeric value itself, for e.g., adding a custom thousand separator. What I was missing was the use of `sprintf`.

Comment: I see. Yes,  `sprintf` is very useful, but if you are completely new to string manipulation/concatenation, also take a look at `paste`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [output hook](http://yihui.name/knitr/hooks/#output_hooks) `inline` can be used to style output from `\Sexpr{}`. This is as simple as

```
knit_hooks$set(inline = function(x) { sprintf("\\textbf{%s}", x)})
```

Just define an arbitrary function that takes an argument `x` and returns the string to be printed. In this example I used `\textbf` to make the output bold, but this can be extended to any LaTeX commands.

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13698163/2706569), Yihui suggests an improvement that still takes the default inline hook into account. This ensures rounding as usually performed by the default hook:

```
hook_inline <- knit_hooks$get('inline')
knit_hooks$set(inline = function(x) { sprintf("\\textbf{%s}", hook_inline(x))})
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. For the sake of completion, the text highlighting works with:
`hook_inline <- knit_hooks$get('inline')
knit_hooks$set(inline = function(x) {sprintf("\\hl{%s}", hook_inline(x))})`
with `\usepackage{soul}` in the preamble for `\hl`.

Comment: I am new in this type of context. So, I can't understand how to fit this two lines of code for an inline command. For example, for this line, `There were \Sexpr{N} people in the company,` where to write hook_inline codes?

Comment: @user1896653 The code goes into an code chunk, as shown in the question: between `<<>>=` and `@`. See, for example, here: https://yihui.org/knitr/demo/minimal/