# How to use %in% in Sexpr in R/Sweave?

Tags: r, latex, sweave, rnw

Here is my code in a Rnw file :

```
\Sexpr{length(which(x %in% c('a', 'b')))}
```

As % is the syntax for comments, this code doesn't work.
How to use %in% in Sexpr in R/Sweave ?

Comment: Have you tried escaping it?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work either.

Comment: If it's true that it doesn't work inline, you could add it to a code block, saving the output to a variable. Then just call the variable name inline.

Comment: I would have preferred to avoid but if there is no alternative, I will do so !

Comment: You can use `is.element` instead of `%in%`.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot mark questions as duplicate but I got the answer from here and by Yihui: [\Sexpr{} special LaTeX characters ($, &, %, # etc.) in .Rnw-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13694009/sexpr-special-latex-characters-etc-in-rnw-file/13698163#comment93956129_13698163)

The following code will allow special latex characters to be used inline in \Sexpr so you can use %in%. It's a more general question than the one you posted.

```
hook_inline = knit_hooks$get('inline')
knit_hooks$set(inline = function(x) {
  if (is.character(x)) x = knitr:::escape_latex(x)
  hook_inline(x)
})
```