# Special character (ampersand) inside LaTeX environment

Tags: r, latex, knitr, r-markdown, pandoc

I have a character vector containing ampersand (`&`) that displays correctly when used *outside* LaTeX environment, such as `\begin{itemize}`.

This works:

```
---
output:
  pdf_document
---

`r "Guns & Roses"`
```

---

The above code runs without error, meaning that either `knitr` or `rmarkdown` escapes the ampersand automatically.

Now, when the same R character vector with ampersand is specified inside LaTeX environment, following error is thrown: `! Misplaced alignment tab character &.`:

```
---
output:
  pdf_document
---

\begin{itemize}
\item `r "Guns & Roses"`
\end{itemize}
```

Comment: The `&` character has a special meaning in LaTeX. To use it literally, you need to escape it: `\&` which is `\\&` in R. I think this question should be closed because it is not about `knitr` but about LaTeX and in the latter case a duplicate of [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95270/how-do-i-use-literally-in-latex).

Comment: Well aware of need to escape ampersand in LaTeX `\&`. Question is different though: about `knitr` or `rmarkdown` way of handling the ampersand differently within environment vs outside the environment. First example (minimal and reproducible, if you actually run it) demonstrates that either `knitr` or `rmarkdown` somehow escapes ampersand automatically.

Comment: I see, thank you for the clarification. Not tested yet, but I think the difference is due to `pandoc`. It escapes special LaTeX characters only *outside* of LaTeX environments. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33689497/2706569) explains a similar case where `pandoc` escapes some characters but not others.

Comment: Thank you, that is additive info regarding the `pandoc`. If that's true, maybe I should re-tag from `knitr` to `pandoc` and leave `rmarkdown`. `rmarkdown` depends on `knitr` anyway, AFAIK. Does `pandoc` have option/extension to escape also *inside* LaTeX environments?

Comment: I don't know how and I don't think so, sorry. You can disable the [raw_tex](http://pandoc.org/README.html#raw-tex) extension but then *all* LaTeX is escaped. The problem is, `pandoc` cannot "know" what to escape and what not, AFAIK.

Comment: Inspired by [this SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9896173/way-to-automatically-escape-characters-etc-using-knitr), I think the way to go is wrapping the `R` inliner into `\verb`atim environment: `\verb| ``r "Guns & Roses"``|`. Broader solution than messing with each `R` string by adding backslash.

Comment: If that works for you (despite the ugly formatting) you may want to use `knitr::knit_hooks$set(inline = function(x) {return(paste("\\verb|", x, "|"))})`.

Comment: Thanks, interesting. I've tried inserting that hook line as first chunk of the `Rmd` file, but still get `! Misplaced alignment tab character &`. Would you mind posting the complete reproducible code as an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason why the first snippet in the question runs without errors but the second does not is that the `&` needs to be escaped in LaTeX and `pandoc` escapes it in the first case but not in the second.

This is because `pandoc` (with the extension [raw_tex](http://pandoc.org/README.html#raw-tex)) doesn't escape "material between the begin and end tags".

`knitr`'s [output hook](http://yihui.name/knitr/hooks/#output_hooks) `inline` can be used to solve the problem.

One solution—that works for the OP, according to the comments—is to enclose output from R inline expressions in a `verbatim` environment where the `&` characer is allowed.

````
---
output:
  pdf_document
---

```{r, echo = FALSE}
knitr::knit_hooks$set(inline = function(x) {
  return(paste("\\verb|", x, "|"))
})
```

\begin{itemize}
\item `r "Guns & Roses"`
\end{itemize}
````

Alternatively, the following output hook for inline expressions could be used to replace all `&` by `\&`:

```
knitr::knit_hooks$set(inline = function(x) {
  return(gsub(pattern = "&", 
              replacement = "\\&", 
              x = x, 
              fixed = TRUE))
})
```

Comment: Thanks @CL. I used the output hook for inline expressions you shared above, and wrapped it within an `if` to only run if `latex` output, and this worked beautifully for my purposes!

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem in Rmarkdown, where the Ampersand was supposed to show up in the labels of a ggplot. Using the output hooks CL suggested did not work for me. However, what did help was to put this specific ggplot into its own code chunk (note that I did not escape the ampersand! It is only part of a string variable)– Perhaps a strange workaround for Rmarkdown hickups but seems to work.